# Zend ACL - unusual errors in log file

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

This is a bit weird because I am seeing these bunch of errors in my log files and none of them correspond to any resources that I have. Infact I dont even recognize any of these resources that show up in the error files

```
2010-12-26T12:19:46+00:00 ERR (3): Error Message Resource 'res' not found
2010-12-26T12:19:46+00:00 ERR (3): Stack Trace #0 /var/www/application/library/Zend/Acl.php(691): Zend_Acl->get('res')
#1 /var/www/application/library/My/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php(29): Zend_Acl->isAllowed('guest', 'res', '2127250264.html')

2010-12-26T12:50:21+00:00 ERR (3): Error Message Resource 'fcs' not found
2010-12-26T12:50:21+00:00 ERR (3): Stack Trace #0 /var/www/application/library/Zend/Acl.php(691): Zend_Acl->get('fcs')
#1 /var/www/application/library/My/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php(29): Zend_Acl->isAllowed('guest', 'fcs', 'ident2')


2010-12-26T12:50:22+00:00 ERR (3): Error Message Resource 'open' not found
2010-12-26T12:50:22+00:00 ERR (3): Stack Trace #0 /var/www/application/library/Zend/Acl.php(691): Zend_Acl->get('open')
#1 /var/www/application/library/My/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php(29): Zend_Acl->isAllowed('guest', 'open', '1')
```

Resource res, fcs, open or the 2127250264.html - these are not resources in my application - so I'm not sure what these errors mean.

Can anyone shed any light on how I can go about debugging this.

---

EDIT

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
  private $_acl = null;

  public function __construct(Zend_Acl $acl) {
    $this->_acl = $acl;
  }

  public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {  

    //As in the earlier example, authed users will have the role user
    $role = (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity())
          ? 'user'
          : 'guest';

    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
    $action = $request->getActionName();

    $requestUri = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('lastRequest');       
    // Temporary fix not to save view-image as last requested URL
    if(strpos($requestUri, 'snapshot')==false && $controller != 'register' && $controller != 'login' && $action != 'view-image' && $action != 'play-video' && $action != 'config') {
        //save the requested action only if it is not login
        $session->lastRequestUri = $requestUri;
    }


    if(!$this->_acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action)) {    
      //If the user has no access we send him elsewhere by changing the request
      $request->setModuleName('default')
              ->setControllerName('login')
              ->setActionName('log');
    }
  }
}
```

---

And this is the class where I have defined the resources

```
class My_Acl extends Zend_Acl {
  public function __construct() {
    //Add a new role called "guest"
    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'));

    //Add a role called user, which inherits from guest
    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'), 'guest');

    //Add a resource called page
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('video'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('error'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('index'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('login'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('register'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('profile'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('edit-profile'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('css'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('js'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('images'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('snapshots'));



    //Finally, we want to allow guests to view pages
    $this->allow('guest', 'css');
    $this->allow('guest', 'js');
    $this->allow('guest', 'snapshots');
    $this->allow('guest', 'images');
    $this->allow('guest', 'error');
    $this->allow('guest', 'login');
    $this->allow('guest', 'index');
    $this->allow('guest', 'register');
    $this->allow('guest', 'profile','view-profile');
    $this->allow('guest', 'profile','view-image');
    $this->allow('guest', 'profile','all-videos');
    $this->allow('guest', 'profile','all-fans');
    $this->allow('guest', 'profile','favorite-artists');
    $this->allow('guest', 'profile','favorite-videos');
    $this->allow('guest', 'video','display-thumb');

    $this->allow('guest', 'video', 'config');
    $this->allow('guest', 'video', 'play');
    $this->allow('guest', 'video', 'play-video');
    $this->allow('guest', 'video', 'new-videos');
    $this->allow('guest', 'video', 'category');
    $this->allow('guest', 'video', 'index');
    $this->allow('guest', 'video', 'search');
    $this->allow('user', 'video');
    $this->allow('user', 'profile');
  }
}
```

Comment: show us the code in `Acl.php` please .

Comment: Have updated the question with the code - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would guess (without seeing your My/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php) that you derive your resources from controller/module/action name. And someone accessed URL that you would not expect to be visited (maybe from older version of you application, that used to have different URLs).

Comment: No this is an absolutely new site - that hasnt been pushed to production yet - still in testing - so there is no older version of the site. I have posted the code for Acl.php - Thanks for your time

Comment: I assume none of the defined routes call controllers or actions (being used as resources and privileges, respectively) like you are seeing in the error logs. Maybe post your routing, as well? Otherwise, it sounds like @Tomáš answer seems most likely. Are you sure no one else is accessing the app, perhaps using unexpected urls? Or perhaps some javascript or css calling for something unexpected?

Comment: Thanks David - well I'm positive no one else is accessing the app - cos I get similar errors while testing on localhost as well - the resource names are different like today morning on my localhost - the errors were Resource 'announce' not found or Resource 'scrape' not found - I have done a search on these resource names on all the css and js files and other files I have with no luck - but I havent looked into the external js files hosted by facebook and stuff. Thanks

Comment: for me it seems like something tries to access something somewhere, but it access your server instead. I would check and search apache log on localhost for those URLs. You would see where exactly the request goes to ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same strange messages recently. As Tomáš suggested, I looked through apache access logs and found that there were missing files that were requested by one of my css sheets.

So when you have a missing file in your public folder - you might get errors like

`2011-02-22T02:44:49+03:00 DEBUG (7): Resource 'css' not found
/usr/local/Zend/Acl.php(777): Zend_Acl->get('css')
/home/www/public_html/application/plugins/AccessControl.php(61): Zend_Acl->isAllowed('guest', 'css', 'img')`

To solve this - simply find and remove requests for missing files in your css, html etc